# fetch data from rest api and display to the dropdown on UI using Oracle JET

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, oracle-jet

trying to get data in drop-down from the rest api response

```
var self = this;
  $(document).ready(
            function()
            {
                 val = [];
                alert('test');
                restApiFactory.getReleases().fetch({
            success:function(model,response){
                console.log(response);
                this.val = ko.observableArray(response['uri']);
                //self.books(response);
                function ValueModel() {
    this.val = ko.observableArray();
  }
  ko.applyBindings(new ValueModel(), document.getElementById('form1'));
            }
        })
                //console.log(self.books());
              //ko.applyBindings(null, document.getElementById('form-container'));
            }
        );
define(['ojs/ojcore','ojs/ojmodel'],function(oj){

var apiFactory = {};
apiFactory.baseUrl = 'restapi.get.url';
apiFactory.getReleases = function(){
    var Book = oj.Model.extend({
       url: apiFactory.baseUrl,
       idAttribute:'page'
    });
    return new Book();
}
return apiFactory;
```

});

getting error :
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "ojComponent: {component:'ojSelect',value:val,rootAttributes:{style:'max-width:20em'}}"
Message: val is not defined

Comment: rest api response :

    
    {test: "abc",

children: [
{
uri: "/abc",
folder: true
},
{
uri: "/xyz",
folder: true
}
],
uri: "google.com"
}

Comment: need to get abc xyz in the dropdown

Comment: You have to replace forward slash (/) with some other special character like $. Then you can get the value of `uri` and when you get this value again you have change this $ with forward slash (/).

Comment: For replacing the forward slash (/) with $. You can use `someString.replace(/\//g, "$");`